# Showing a set is closed and bounded but not compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

How can I prove that the interval $[0,∞)$ is closed and bounded in $(\mathbb{R},d)$ but not compact under the distance function $ d(x, y) = \min \{|x − y|,1 \}$ ?

Comment: There are three facts you want to prove. Can you prove any of them? What progress have you made, where are you stuck or confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This set is bounded: For any $x,y$ in this set $d(x,y)\le 1$.

This set is closed: Take any convergent sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that converges to $L$, say. Then for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(x_n,L)<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. This is not possible if $L<0$, because in that case the above condition would not hold for $\epsilon=\min\left\{\frac{|L|}2,\frac12\right\}$.

The set is not compact: Take the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where $x_n=n$. Then $\{x_n\}\in[0,\infty)$ but $\{x_n\}$ has no convergent subsequence.